# HTML5 validation not working in IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate a Select field in using HTML5; it's working perfectly fine in Chrome and FF browser, but when I tried in IE and Safari, it's not working. I tried using a JavaScript to get it to work, but I'm still having the same problem. Please help me out. The sample of my code is here:

- http://i1159.photobucket.com/albums/p637/Apulo_Cosmas/validate.jpg

How can I fix it so the same code works with all four browsers?

Comment: You have a typo in your onclick, `validat` instead of `validate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an `onclick` on the submit button, it's better to have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(f) {
    if (f.empty.value == '') { alert('you must enter text'); return false; }
    if (f.select_box.value == '') { alert('you must select something'); return false; }
}
</script>

<form name="form1" action="test2" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
...
<input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

Edit: The `validate(this)` will call the `validate` function and pass itself (the form) as `f`. Then, the fields within the form can be refered to by name (e.g. `empty` and `select_box`)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Jack, how can i use the exact function to validate an email field?    if (f.email.value == '') { alert('Pls Enter you correct email!'); return false; }  but i want the field to be able to filter and select a proper email format using all this /^[a-zA-Z]+([_\.=]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)'(\.[a-zA-Z](2,4)) and so on. Thanks

Comment: Hi, this should put you on the right track: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/javascript-validation/ - **however** keep in mind that checking email addresses with regular expressions is tricky and you still need server-side validation of course :)

Comment: Hi Jack, please refer to this link: http://i1159.photobucket.com/albums/p637/Apulo_Cosmas/field.jpg 
from that link, you will notice i have 2 fields, 1 is country field and the other is email field.
the select function is working fine from the picture (click check out the link) but one weried issue am having now is that when a user fills up the email field first, the alert box pop's up saying please select country.

Comment: When i click on the ok button (alert ok button), it will take me to the second page instead of returning me to the index page and making sure i select the country before submiting. what do you think will be the problem to this? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, without having seen the code your guess is as good as mine ;-)

Comment: Hi Jack, here is the copy of the code: http://i1159.photobucket.com/albums/p637/Apulo_Cosmas/select.png

Comment: That code seems okay, but perhaps you could use http://codepad.org/ to post the full code instead of a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, I need the whole thing; I can't do anything with a partial script.

Comment: That code should just work. One thing I should mention to you is that if there's a JavaScript error in your `validate` function, the form will submit. You mentioned earlier that you were working on email validation, so perhaps that was causing an error? To debug you can surround your code with `try ... catch` followed by `return false`.

Comment: Well if you notice, i dint validate the emaill field, am just using the old validation i have which is HTML5 validation(required). And secondly if i run the same code outside my application on 2 blank pages, it works fine but if i get it to my application, it will be having that mistake.

Comment: Ah, in that case you're having a different kind of problem ;-) you might have to post another question for that related to Wordpress I'm guessing?

Comment: Alright, thanks Jack for the effort to help. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Use parsley library it supports cross browser validations for reference check this link : http://www.247techblog.com/use-html5-validations-internet-explorer-tutorial-guide/

Answer (score 0):

I used the [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
              var button = document.getElementById("submit-button");
              button.onclick = function() {
                $('#form-name').validate();
                if( $('#form-name').valid() == false) {
                  return false;
                    }
                }
            };
    </script>
```